# How to connect elastic beanstalk to azure sql

Tags: azure-sql-database, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had made an application to connect to Azure SQL. However, after I had deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk, it cannot connect to my db. But I had tested it on my local environment. It works fine indeed.

I had tried to put the public EIP of EC2 to my Azure SQL server firewall rule. Also, I had created a VPC to host the application. But nothing work. Also, I had tried to create inbound/outbound rule for VPC to connect to Azure SQL subnet but still not work. [[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWVoE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz0cf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYac2.png)
I had also tried to include public NAT gateway IP address in Azure SQL's fire wall rule. Also not working. May I kindly receive advices on how to deal with it?

Comment: have you checked connection string is correct or not?

Comment: I had checked the connection string, but still doesn't work. I choose to deploy my app directly on Azure instead. And it works